# In F#, how to add an interface to a partial class (from another project)

Tags: interface, f#

I am new to this. I have an Account partial class brought down from a web server (WCF) as:

```
 public partial class Account : object
    {
        
        private System.DateTime birthdateField;
        
        private int chart_numberField;
        
        private System.Nullable<bool> do_not_seeField;
        
        private string firstnameField;
        
        private string lastnameField;
        
        private string miField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.DateTime birthdate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.birthdateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.birthdateField = value;
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public int chart_number
        {
            get
            {
                return this.chart_numberField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.chart_numberField = value;
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.Nullable<bool> do_not_see
        {
            get
            {
                return this.do_not_seeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.do_not_seeField = value;
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string firstname
        {
            get
            {
                return this.firstnameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.firstnameField = value;
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string lastname
        {
            get
            {
                return this.lastnameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.lastnameField = value;
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string mi
        {
            get
            {
                return this.miField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.miField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is then referenced from my F# project without difficulty. How would I add the following interface to this partial class. (Remember the file creating the partial account class is not under my control).

```
F#
type IAccount =
       abstract member lastName : string with get
       abstract member firstName : string with get
       abstract member mi : string with get
       abstract member birthDate: string with get
       abstract member chartNumber: int with get
       abstract member doNotSee: bool with get
```

TIA

Comment: In .NET you can't add an interface to a type from a different assembly. In any language.

Comment: Ugh...:( Ugh...:(

Comment: Idea: You could create a wrapper class that holds an instance of your partial `Account` class and implements `IAccount` by delegating to that instance.

Comment: to be fair, no dotnet language allows you to add an instance to an type defined in another assembly. C# WILL allow you to add an interface to a class declared in the same assembly - but really its just secretly sticking the two declarations together before compiling..its just syntax suger