# How can I Clone a Partial class in F# and change one property

Tags: f#

I have a partial class in F# - actually referenced to a C# project ( and it was generated in the C# project from a SQL database )

I can easily extract the data from SQL Server - but I want to change one of the properties in the partial class.  I can't easily see a way to copy the class and change one property/ member of the class at the same time.

Note: Ideally - I don't want to change the class structure because it's auto-generated from a different project.

If it was a record - I would use

```
let myRecord3 = { myRecord2 with Y = 100; Z = 2 }
```

but it's not and I can't quite get my head around who I would do this. thanks for your time.

Comment: There was recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66094925/in-f-how-to-add-an-interface-to-a-partial-class-from-another-project) about extending partial class. You can't extend partial class in .net

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request, you have an object and you want to create a second object that has some new values but is otherwise a copy of the original. I think you can do this by creating a copy constructor and then specifying new values for whatever properties you want when you call it. Here's an example:

```
type Person() =

        // copy constructor
    new (person : Person) as this =
        Person() then
            this.FirstName <- person.FirstName
            this.MiddleName <- person.MiddleName
            this.LastName <- person.LastName
        
    member val FirstName = "" with get, set
    member val MiddleName = "" with get, set
    member val LastName = "" with get, set

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

        // first object
    let p1 = Person(FirstName = "John", MiddleName = "Q", LastName = "Public")
    printfn "%s %s %s" p1.FirstName p1.MiddleName p1.LastName

        // second object is copied from the first, but with a different first name
    let p2 = Person(p1, FirstName = "Julian")
    printfn "%s %s %s" p2.FirstName p2.MiddleName p2.LastName

    0
```

The output is:

```
John Q Public
Julian Q Public
```